# iOS-Using upload image on Google Drive Api(error "Assertion failure in: GTLServer...")

Tags: ios, ios6, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive in my iOS app. I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
2013-06-17 14:38:57.964 GTL Demo[6495:11303] *** Assertion failure in -[GTLService uploadFetcherWithRequest:fetcherService:params:](), /Users/huylx612/demo2/google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/Objects/GTLService.m:565
2013-06-17 14:38:58.049 GTL Demo[6495:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'GTMHTTPUploadFetcher needed'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e01012 0x1307e7e 0x1e00e78 0xd9d6d0 0x3d0ba 0x3cb55 0x3de06 0x42a89 0x3642 0x2ee4 0x44ee3e 0xed7ed11 0xed772fd 0xedfa9f8 0x131b6b0 0xd47765 0x1d84f3f 0x1d8496f 0x1da7734 0x1da6f44 0x1da6e1b 0x21947e3 0x2194668 0x24bffc 0x26bd 0x25e5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"];
    GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the Google Drive iOS Quickstart";
    file.mimeType = @"image/png";

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)image);

    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                       completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error)
                {
                      [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                      if (error == nil)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
                      }
                }];
}
```

Help me!

Answer (score 2):

`GTMHTTPUploadFetcher` is not linked, please add `-ObjC -all_load` to the Other Linker Flag options.

Comment: @user2492521, accept the answer as an answer instead of thanking.

Comment: Not working for me either, I have added both the flags, anything else I can try?