# Upload an image to Google Drive public folder

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, dropbox

I want to upload an image (from UIImage) to my own Google Drive public folder, from an iOS app, when a user chooses an image from his Photos Library.

Is it possible to upload a file to a Google Drive public folder without showing the user a consent screen?

If not, can it be done in Dropbox?

Thanks

Comment: I find your post quite complicated, so please correct me if I understand it incorrectly. Are you referring to uploading images to someone else's Google Drive account (ie. someone upload photos to a Google Drive that does not belong to him)?

These related posts - [Uploading to Someone Else's Google Drive](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30285/uploading-to-someone-elses-google-drive) or code related - [iOS-Using upload image on Google Drive Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143038/ios-using-upload-image-on-google-drive-apierror-assertion-failure-in-gtlserve) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the links you sent later. I meant users will upload to MY Google Drive from within three app.

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS app will need an Access Token for your drive. There are a number of ways of doing this, for example by embedding a Refresh Token in your app. You will need to carefully consider the security implications of doing that. My recommendation would be to host a "proxy" kind of service on App Engine and upload to that, which will then in turn upload it to your Drive account.